# Esta correcto el programa?(no se si lo que me piden y lo que he hecho es lo mismo es sobre estructura de almacenamiento complejas

Tags: java

Os cuento estoy haciendo un trabajo os dejo el enunciado y mi código.

Ejercicio:

> Queremos realizar una aplicación que permita manejar la información
>   relativa a los partes de trabajo de una empresa de reparación de
>   electrodomésticos, cada uno de los cuales con los siguientes datos:
>   Nombre del cliente, dirección del cliente, fecha del parte, nombre del
>   trabajador que lo va a realizar, estado ((P)endiente/(R)ealizado),
>   fecha prevista de reparación, tiempo empleado en minutos, descripción
>   del arreglo y la relación de los materiales empleados así como la
>   cantidad utilizada, que deberá ser rellenada cuando el parte de
>   trabajo se haya realizado y que deberá ser una collection.

primera clase es el parte de trabajo

```
public class ParteDeTrabajo {

    private String nombreCliente;
    private LocalDate fechaParte;
    private String nombreTrabajador;
    private char estado;
    private LocalDate fechaReparacion;
    private double tiempoReparacion;
    private String descripcionArreglo;
    private ArrayList<Material> materiales;

    public String getNombreCliente() {
        return nombreCliente;
    }

    public void setNombreCliente(String nombreCliente) {
        this.nombreCliente = nombreCliente;
    }

    public LocalDate getFechaParte() {
        return fechaParte;
    }

    public void setFechaParte(LocalDate fechaParte) {
        this.fechaParte = fechaParte;
    }

    public String getNombreTrabajador() {
        return nombreTrabajador;
    }

    public void setNombreTrabajador(String nombreTrabajador) {
        this.nombreTrabajador = nombreTrabajador;
    }

    public char getEstado() {
        return estado;
    }

    public void setEstado(char estado) {
        if (this.estado == 'p' || this.estado == 'R') {
            this.estado = estado;
        }
    }

    public LocalDate getFechaReparacion() {
        return fechaReparacion;
    }

    public void setFechaReparacion(LocalDate fechaReparacion) {
        this.fechaReparacion = fechaReparacion;
    }

    public double getTiempoReparacion() {
        return tiempoReparacion;
    }

    public void setTiempoReparacion(double tiempoReparacion) {
        if (this.tiempoReparacion >= 0) {
            this.tiempoReparacion = tiempoReparacion;
        }
    }

    public String getDescripcionArreglo() {
        return descripcionArreglo;
    }

    public void setDescripcionArreglo(String descripcionArreglo) {
        this.descripcionArreglo = descripcionArreglo;
    }

    public ArrayList<Material> getMateriales() {
        return materiales;
    }

    public void setMateriales(ArrayList<Material> materiales) {
        this.materiales = materiales;
    }

    public ParteDeTrabajo(String nombreCliente, LocalDate fechaParte, String nombreTrabajador, char estado, LocalDate fechaReparacion, double tiempoReparacion, String descripcionArreglo, List<Material> materiales) {
        this.nombreCliente = nombreCliente;
        this.fechaParte = fechaParte;
        this.nombreTrabajador = nombreTrabajador;
        setEstado(estado);
        this.fechaReparacion = fechaReparacion;
        setTiempoReparacion(tiempoReparacion);
        this.descripcionArreglo = descripcionArreglo;
        this.materiales = materiales;
    }

    public ParteDeTrabajo() {
        this.nombreCliente = "";
        this.fechaParte = null;
        this.nombreTrabajador = "";
        this.estado = 'p';
        this.fechaReparacion = null;
        this.tiempoReparacion = 0;
        this.descripcionArreglo = "";
        this.materiales = null;
    }

}
```

la segunda clase material

```
public class Material {

    private String material;
    private double cantidadUsada;

    public Material(String material, double cantidadUsada) {
        this.material = material;
        setCantidadUsada(cantidadUsada);
    }

    public Material() {
        this.material = "";
        this.cantidadUsada = 0;
    }

    public String getMaterial() {
        return material;
    }

    public void setMaterial(String material) {
        this.material = material;
    }

    public double getCantidadUsada() {
        return cantidadUsada;
    }
    /* 
     Entiendo que si lo apuntas es porque lo usas entonces como minimo la canidad
     es 0 sin incluir este osea 0´0000000000000000000000......1
     */

    public void setCantidadUsada(double cantidadUsada) {
        if (cantidadUsada > 0) {
            this.cantidadUsada = cantidadUsada;
        }
    }
}
```

Yo creo que esta bien pero como estoy empezando no se si el `Collection` que me pide vale el `ArrayList` o necesito otra cosa.

Comment: Viendo tu diseño *a vuelo de pájaro*, tengo dos críticas que hacerte: la 1ª es que se echa de menos una clase `Trabajador`. La 2ª es que metes en la clase `Material` la lógica relativa a la cantidad usada. No me parece correcto. Tienes que pensar las clases como una entidad. La clase `Material` debe representar lo que es un `Material` en sí. La cantidad que se use de un determinado material en una reparación no tiene nada que ver con la entidad en sí, sino con la clase que usa esa entidad, que en este caso sería `ParteDeTrabajo`. Creo que es esa clase la que debe hacer ese cálculo.

Comment: No hay clase trabajador porque no me dicen nada de ello y como mucho iba a tener un nombre. Una clase tiene varios atributos, lo mismo que la clase trabajador podría tener atributo sueldo la clase material tiene tipo material y cantidad. 
Puesto que el enunciado pone  la relación de los materiales empleados así como la cantidad utilizada, que deberá ser rellenada cuando el parte de trabajo se haya realizado y que deberá ser una collection.
Entiendo que eso va en arraylist o en lo que sea y se me a ocurrido hacerlo asi

Comment: Es incorrecto tu diseño, un campo calculado no es parte intrínseca de un ente (Clase), sino que pertenece a otro contexto. Cuando declaras una propiedad *cantidadMaterial*  en la clase `Material` es como si dijeras que *todo material existe con un cálculo de su cantidad en todas las situaciones*, lo cual no es cierto. Ocurre lo mismo con la edad por ejemplo en una clase `Persona`, si declaras una propiedad `edad` es como si dijeras que una persona nace con una edad, si lo piensas bien no es cierto, una persona nace en una `fecha` y a partir de ella calculas la edad **cuando lo necesites**.

Comment: Pero es que no es un campo calculado tu no tienes un total y luego queda x y lo que has gastado en un calculo lo que había menos lo que hay. Esto es un dato he gastado 2litro de aceite es un dato que yo apunto no se calcula

Answer (score 3):

Por el enunciado parece que el único requisito es que sea cualquier clase que forme parte de las [colecciones](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) de java. Como puedes ver, efectivamente ArrayList forma parte de la interfaz Collection de Java.

Suelen pedir estas cosas para acostumbrar al estudiante a utilizar las API de los lenguajes, de manera que entiendan que ya hay soluciones a determinados problemas y no estén constantemente descubiendo la rueda o para descubrir algunas características más avanzadas del lenguaje, como por ejemplo los tipos parametrizados.

De todos modos, y si me lo permites, te recomendaría que te replantearas el enfoque de los objetos. Recuerda que la POO permite abstraer objetos y plasmarlos en código de manera parecida a la vida real. En el caso de la clase material, ¿crees que para definir un material deberías poner cuánto has utilizado?. Lo normal es que los materiales (hablo de materiales porque es tu caso, pero llámalo como prefieras) los definas en función de sus características y luego los añadas al parte de trabajo (que será otro objeto dentro de tu programa). De esta manera, el material es independiente de la cantidad que uses (que en la vida real, estará en un almacen, vinculado a un stock...) y será un objeto al que podrás añadir tantas características como quieras posteriormente (refactorización) sin demasiados problemas.

Igualmente no parece tener lógica que definas un cliente en un parte de trabajo. Lo normal es que un cliente sea una entidad independiente, de manera que lo puedas vincular a un parte, a una factura, a una reclamación, devolución... Es decir, un cliente no puedes definirlo en un parte de trabajo; debe ser un objeto independiente.

En estos casos lo normal es que los objetos más elaborados vinculen (normalmente por agregación o composición) otros objetos más básicos. Esta separación te permitirá mejorar tu programa con facilidad (refactorización) y encontrar errores más fácilmente (depuración)

Utilizar las características de un lenguaje (especialmente su paradigma) es fundamental y normalmente suele valorarse en la ejecución de los ejercicios. No tiene sentido que sepas utilizar clases parametrizadas pero no diseñes adecuadamente tu estructura de objetos.

Ánimo y un saludo.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo contigo, se me escapó señalar al OP que faltaba también una clase `Cliente`. Y otra clase que falta es una clase `Trabajador`. Y hasta quizá una clase `Persona` de la que deberían extender `Cliente` y `Trabajador`, pero como es un ejercicio, no sé tampoco si ya abordaron en dicho curso el tema de la *herencia*.

Comment: Sí, es evidente que faltan clases, pero más que señalárselas concretamente quería que viera el concepto general de jerarquía de objetos. Siempre será mejor que él mismo se enfrente al diseño, así aprenderá de sus aciertos y errores. La herencia es algun fundamental, como bien señalas y más aún si vas a trabajar con clases parametrizadas. Un saludo.

Comment: Me parece un poco rizar el rizo, puesto que tu no tienes xq tener una lista de clientes. cada parte de trabajo tiene un cliente a cuyo nombre no puedes acceder si tienes una clase cliente salvo que sea una clase padre. la clase trabajador tampoco tiene sentido por lo mismo y porque no tenemos datos.  vamos mi inexperta opinion todo sea dicho

Comment: Siento dicentir con la respuesta. En realiad, lo que hizo carlos cumple a la perfeccion el pobre enunciado que le dieron. Uds estan viendo la pregunta como un sistema compleja, y no es mas que un ejercicio para demostrar si entendio como armar una clase. La respuesta es ultra correcta, pero en otro escenario :(. Tuve que leer varias veces el enunciado para ver si realmente le estaban pidiendo algo tan simple, y es asi. Por lo cual no entiendo ni el sentido de la pregunta, ya que podemos decir que si, y despues llega su profe y le dice que queria otra cosa :(